# Using Shared preferenece , checkbox and button

Tags: android, button, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I am making a program in which I want to use an `Activity` 
as a splash screen which shows a list of instruction which 
i am using as a background image, a checkbox and a button. 
I want that when the `CheckBox` is `clicked` or `onChecked` and 
then I click the button, that activity should not be seen 
again at startup.

[image]

This is what I am doing but still no use

```
CheckBox cb;
SharedPreferences sp;
Button btn;
int result;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    sp = (SharedPreferences) PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    OnCheckedChangeListener cb1 = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(cb.isChecked()){



            }
            else{


                result = sp.getInt("showActivity", -1);
                if(result == 0){
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setClass(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(cb1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("showActivity",cb.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "dgdgd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClass(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is your main/initial activity?

Comment: This is a splash activity, I want when the user clicks on checkbox this activity should not be seen again and if he does not click the ckeckbox this activity should be again seen at startup

Comment: But where do you have that logic? Can you post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to use `Share-Preference` to achieve, put condition within onCreate that `user checked initially or not` and call appropriate screen as per boolean. Try below code.

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences pref;
    boolean state;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pref = getSharedPreferences("PackageName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        state= pref.getBoolean("State", false);

        if(state){
            Intent intent= new Intent(SplashScreen.this,NextActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }else{

            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);



        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        Button btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


        chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    state=true; 
                }else{
                    state=false;
                }


            }
        });

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Editor edit= pref.edit();
                edit.putBoolean("State", state);
                edit.commit();

                Intent intent= new Intent(SplashScreen.this,NextActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });

        }

    }



}
```

Comment: Now if i want to go to back to SplashScreen activity using Intent, it is not happening??

Comment: ooh, In case if checkbox is not checked then user can go back to splash, is it?

Comment: Even if the checkbox is checked I want to return to SplashActivty from another activity. For example: I am using a menu, and from that i want to go to SplashActivity but when the application starts the Splash activity should not be seen on start if its is checked

Comment: But in this case from next open an app splash wont show you, once user checked the checkbox.

Comment: Simply remove `finish();` from button click.

Comment: Then you need to clear your stored preference from where (menu) you calling splash screen So it will display splash and try to understand the code and go further.

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckBox cb;
SharedPreferences sp;
Button btn;
// never used
//int result;
private final String DONT_SHOW_ACTIVITY = "dontShowActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sp = (SharedPreferences) PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
    // default value is false, means you will start MainActivity at first time.
    // And if you hava checked "dont show again", MainActivity will finish itself 
    // immediately, and start the SecondActivity.
    if(sp.getBoolean(DONT_SHOW_ACTIVITY, false)){
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        this.finish();    
    }        
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            editor.putBoolean(DONT_SHOW_ACTIVITY,cb.isChecked());
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "dgdgd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClass(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // you should finish MainActivity here, or you can press back return from 
            // SecondActivity to MainActivity.
            this.finish()
    }
});
```

}